# In JFrog container registry, how to pull a image which name contains forward slash,for example, bitnami/nginx?

Tags: docker, artifactory, jfrog-container-registry

I add a remote docker repository, using the default config of Artifactory.
I can pull images like alpine and hello-world through artifactory remote repo, but when the image name has a "/", usually a [group id]/[image id] format, for example "elastic/filebeat", the artifactory log shows it can not find the manifest file.
`docker pull elastic/filebeat` directly from docker registry is ok.
I can not believe that no one encounter this problem on internet, did i missing something?

Comment: Is that image even there in that registry?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out. I use accelerate mirror other than docker official hub, when pulling a image, the mirror needs a 'library' prefix, otherwise it cannot find the manifests file; but when the image name contains forword slash, you cannot add 'library' prefix, WTF! Waste my entire day.

Comment: yea.... same here. Pulling from docker hub is fine , but from our artifactory mirror I get `Error response from daemon: manifest for artifactory.mycompany.com/hub-docker-remote/library/redhat/ubi9:latest not found: manifest unknown: The named manifest is not known to the registry`